# AVAudioPlayerNode перемотка времени

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, аудио

Для проигрывания файла использую AVAudioPlayerNode. Пишу под mac. Не могу разобраться, каким образом, организовать перемотку времени и трека вперед. Перемотку назад организовал вот так:

```
- (IBAction)BackTrack:(id)sender {
[track pause];
NSError *nsErr = nil;
[engine startAndReturnError:&nsErr];
if (!nsErr) {
    AVAudioFormat *outputFormat = [track outputFormatForBus:0];


    AVAudioTime *startTime = [AVAudioTime timeWithSampleTime:track.lastRenderTime.sampleTime + 5 *outputFormat.sampleRate atRate:outputFormat.sampleRate];
    NSLog(@"%@", startTime);
    [track playAtTime:startTime];
}
```

Или как хотя бы снять текущее значение времени в AVAudioPlayerNode?

Comment: добавил вот такой кусок  `AVAudioTime *currentTime2 = [AVAudioTime timeWithHostTime:track.lastRenderTime.hostTime sampleTime:track.lastRenderTime.sampleTime - 0.009 * track.lastRenderTime.sampleTime atRate:sampleRate];
    [track playAtTime:currentTime2];` Однако оно переодически откидывает в начало трэка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Организовал перемотку по слайдеру:

```
[track pause];

AVAudioFormat *outputFormat = [track outputFormatForBus:0];
if ([_TimeSlider floatValue] > VCount){
AVAudioTime *currentTime = [AVAudioTime timeWithHostTime:track.lastRenderTime.hostTime sampleTime:track.lastRenderTime.sampleTime - [_TimeSlider floatValue]*44100 atRate:outputFormat.sampleRate];
[track scheduleBuffer:buffer atTime:currentTime options:1 completionHandler:nil];
[_TimeSlider setFloatValue:[_TimeSlider floatValue]];
     NSLog(@"%@", currentTime);
}
//AVAudioFormat *outputFormat = [track outputFormatForBus:0];
//AVAudioTime *sometime = [AVAudioTime timeWithSampleTime:Player.currentTime atRate:outputFormat.sampleRate];
//[track playAtTime:nil];
else {
    AVAudioTime *currentTime = [AVAudioTime timeWithHostTime:track.lastRenderTime.hostTime sampleTime:track.lastRenderTime.sampleTime - [_TimeSlider floatValue]*44100 atRate:outputFormat.sampleRate];
    [track scheduleBuffer:buffer atTime:currentTime options:1 completionHandler:nil];
    [_TimeSlider setFloatValue:[_TimeSlider floatValue]];
     NSLog(@"%@", currentTime);
}
TIMECOUNT = 0;

[track play];
```